# why Hadoop is not a real-time platform

Tags: hadoop, real-time

i just started to learn Hadoop and  have gone through some sites and i often found that

**"Hadoop is not a real-time platform"** even in SO also

I mess with this and i really cant understand about it . Can any one help me and explain me about this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hadoop was initially designed for batch processing. That means, take a large dataset in input all at once, process it, and write a large output. The very concept of MapReduce is geared towards batch and not real-time. But to be honest, this was only the case at Hadoop's beginning, and now you have plenty of opportunities to use Hadoop in a more real-time way.

First I think it's important to define what you mean by real-time. It could be that you're interested in stream processing, or could also be that you want to run queries on your data that return results in real-time.

For stream processing on Hadoop, natively Hadoop won't provide you with this kind of capabilities, but you can integrate some other projects with Hadoop easily:

- [Storm-YARN](https://github.com/yahoo/storm-yarn) allows you to use Storm on your Hadoop cluster via YARN.
- [Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/) integrates with HDFS to allow you to process streaming data in real-time.

For real-time queries there are also several projects which use Hadoop:

- [Impala](https://github.com/cloudera/impala) from Cloudera uses HDFS but bypasses MapReduce altogether because there's too much overhead otherwise.
- [Apache Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/drill/) is another project that integrates with Hadoop to provide real-time query capabilities.
- The [Stinger](http://hortonworks.com/labs/stinger/) project aims to make Hive itself more real-time.

There are probably other projects that would fit into the list of "Making Hadoop real-time", but these are the most well-known ones.

So as you can see, Hadoop is going more and more towards the direction of real-time and, even if it wasn't designed for that, you have plenty of opportunities to extend it for real-time purposes.